# Multiple table grid with dynamic tables and columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, excel, vba

Let say I have 2 tables initially,

```
Categories
Products
```

Categories table will have a column "No of products" which will show number of products specific category has...

Now `Products` Table is grouped by `CategoryId`, so when user clicks on `number of products` in `Categories` table, he will see `Products` table with specific `CategoryId` group row along with products related to it and there details.

***I already know I can use jQuery Tables plugin or alike to generate dynamic tables, then show/hide based on events.***

But I have another requirement... I need to export these tables (can be 1 or more then around 10) to excel in a single file with 1 sheet for each table. I think this can be done **SOMEHOW** (not sure how yet though)

**Problem**

How can I export all tables to a single excel file, and then make it navigate able like explained above.

I already have done this but using SSRS and asp.net report viewer (which looks awful and isn't easily to modify) so I am thinking about using EITHER jQuery, AngularJs, ASP.NET Grid or alike technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this JS library](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)?

It can create an xlsx file, with multiple sheets etc from JSON.

You will, of course, do all of it client side.

---

I'm assuming that the tables that you're referring to, are either html `<table>` or arrays in your browser. If they're just HTML (for example generated with Razor/ASP.NET), you can also convert them to JSON, ask me in the comments if you need help.

[Here you can find an example from sheet.js for 1 worksheet](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html).

[I have modified this example here](https://embed.plnkr.co/Y6PiCca9cb5LBGanM8gR/), where you have 3 tables, and each is added to its own worksheet. You could create a general method that takes an array of table ids and adds them to 1 worksheet, but I'm too busy to write the code :|

I've included comments in the file that I edited (Export2Excel.js) so that you can understand what is going on. The rest of the files remain unchanged, except index.html that has 3 tables now.

P.S. Don't put script tags in head like in this example, or pages may load this slowly :P

Comment: Thanks @K, I looked at this library before, but I am finding it difficult to figure out how can I use it to add navigation between two sheets easily

Comment: Done! Sorry it took so long, something serious came up.

Comment: +1 for the effort, I am missing how these sheets are navigatable  like if I click on number of products, it will take me to products sheet, I hope I made it clear enough :(

Comment: Do you want to create a hyperlink to a specific worksheet, inside the excel? For example, when the user clicks the text in once cell, he is shown  X worksheet. It would help if you provided a sample page with the tables that you have and want to transfer to excel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108386/discussion-between-mathematics-and-k-gkinis).